# What means the window message 0xc029? (WinAPI)

Tags: winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I'm using `RegisterShellHookWindow` to detect user interaction on windows.
In my `WndProc` I get the message code: `0xC029`.

I looked in WinUser.h but nothing.

What means this message code?
Help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-user, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagea

Comment: Compare it to the value you got back when you called RegisterWindowMessage().

Comment: If you want ot *detect user interaction on windows*, wouldn't it be better to use UI Automation and/or `SetWindowsHookEx()`?

Answer (score -1):

Messages in the range `0xC000..0xFFFF` are generated dynamically at runtime using [`RegisterWindowMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagew), that is why you are not seeing it listed in `winuser.h`.  You can use [`GetClipboardFormatName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboardformatnamew) to get the registered name (as `RegisterWindowMessage()` and `RegisterClipboardFormat()` use the same atom table).